# aggregate value from one table updated in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to insert an aggregated value from one table to other using Update clause.Here is what i did.

```
SELECT Sum(1.0 * volume * speed) / Sum(volume) AS aggregated_speed 
FROM   traffic_data_replica 
GROUP  BY date, 
          id 
ORDER  BY date;
```

I want update this values in other table. This what i have tried.

```
UPDATE traffic_data_aggregated_lanes 
SET    traffic_data_aggregated_lanes.aggregated_speed = (SELECT 
              Sum(1.0 * volume * 
                  speed) / Sum(volume) AS aggregated_speed 
                                                         FROM 
       traffic_data_replica 
                                                         GROUP  BY date, 
                                                                   id 
                                                         ORDER  BY date);
```

Please Help

Comment: "here is what I did" and "here is what I have tried" - **and**? What happened? Given that we don't have your tables or data, it's not like we can try these out for ourselves. You need to tell us what happened, what you *expected* to happen, what the differences are, etc.

Answer (score 0):

relation is not clear.
Somewhat

```
Merge traffic_data_aggregated_lanes a
using (select id, sum(1.0*volume*speed)/sum(volume) as aggregated_speed from  
traffic_data_replica group by date,id) b
on a.id=b.id
when matched then
update   set a.aggregated_speed= b.aggregated_speed
```

Comment: What are the columns with which we can join these two tables? Provide schema of these tables please

Answer (score 0):

we can go by using CTE also i am not sure of data.
So i have given you assumption result

```
WITH CTE AS (
select t.Id,sum(1.0*volume*speed)/sum(volume) as aggregated_speed from  traffic_data_replica t 
group by date,id order by date
)
Select * FROM CTE
update traffic_data_aggregated_lanes    set traffic_data_aggregated_lanes.aggregated_sp= t.aggregated_speed From traffic_data_replica t
INNER JOIN CTE c ON C.Id = t.Id
```